# Filling a HashSet doesn't work the first time -- only on second call

Tags: java, dispose, hashset, jdialog

what i try to do:

I want a HashSet to be filled with new words that the program doesn't know.
User press the "convert" Button on the mainFrame.
The path of a file with words is given on the mainFrame.

If the word is new, a JDialog is opened and asking to insert the new word (so you can change the spelling e.g. first letter big...).

The word is added to the HashSet if the user press the button "write" on the JDialog.

But if i print my HashSet after that, there are only the "old" values shown.
When i press the "convert" Button on the mainFrame the second time, all the Values will be shown correctly in the HashSet.

If anyone can help me i would be very grateful.
If any more Informations are needed let me know.
Here is the code from the ActionListener when the Button "convert" is pressed:

```
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals(convert.getActionCommand())) {
        try {
            //a file with words is given
            fileHandler = new FileIO(path.getText().trim());

            //lines is a ArrayList<String> and returns all the lines
            lines = fileHandler.readFile();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                //words is a String[]
                words = lines.get(i).split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {

                    //hs is a HashSet<String>
                    if (hs.contains(words[j])) {
                        System.out.println("hit: " + words[j]);
                    }else if (!hs.contains(words[j])) {
                        dialog = new JDialog(mainFrame);
                        dialog.setTitle("new Word");
                        dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                        newWord = new JTextField(words[j].toLowerCase());
                        newWord.selectAll();

                        write = new JButton("write");

                        write.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                //can not use the counters "i" or "j" here otherwise it would be so easy...
                                s = newWord.getText().trim();
                                dialog.setVisible(false);
                                if(dialog != null)
                                    dialog.dispose();
                                if (dialog.isActive()) {
                                    System.out.println("active");
                                }else {
                                    //dead code ??? -- never executed so far
                                    System.out.println("finally....done");
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        dialog.add(newWord, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                        dialog.add(write, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                        dialog.pack();
                        dialog.setVisible(true);

                        //todo is filled correctly IF pressed "convert Button" the second time
                        if (!s.contentEquals("")) {
                            words[j] = s;
                            hs.add(s);
                            s = "";
                        }

                    }
                } // words


                //Displays the input line but why not the manipulated from the JDialog input?
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                for (String string : words) {
                    sb.append(string);
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                lines.set(i, sb.toString());
                sb.delete(0, sb.length());

            } // lines
```

code that writes (in a file) and displays my HashSet when i press the "exit" button on the mainFrame:

```
    hashSetHandler = new HashSetIO(WORDS_FILE);
    hashSetHandler.write(hs);
    for (String string : hs) {
        System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: How is `s` declared? It's a member variable of an enclosing class?

Comment: It is a variable declared in the same class like:
public class MainFrame {
     HashSet<String> hs;
that class has a Jframe named "mainFrame" and in the Actionlistener of that Jframe (also declared in the same class) there is my shown code

Comment: You say that the word is not added to the `HashSet`, but your code prints what is in `lines`, not what is in `hs`. Which is it? And when you press "Convert" button the second time, does it prompt you to add the same words, or does it go through without popping any dialogs?

Comment: my code prints what is in "lines" but only the values from the inputFile and not the manipulated Words from the JDialog i have to enter manually.
The HashSet is displayed wrong the first time i press the "convert" Button but perfectly fine if i press it the secound time.

For every word which is not in the HashSet a new dialog is popping and you can modify the word then and write it back (in theory) but it works only if i press the Button "convert" twice

Comment: Your code doesn't display the `HashSet`. What are you talking about?

Comment: yes it is but not in that part of the code...
the HashSet is printed when i press another Button on the "mainFrame"
that writes my HashSet to a File and prints all the entries.
But the hashset has the old values in it only when i press the "convert" button twice it's correctly filled.
i dont know how to post the code in a reply so i edit my question with the other button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider making your `dialog` modal.

Currently you see many pop-ups (one for each new word read from file) when you press `convert`, dont't you?

The difference between modal and "normal" `dialog` will affect your code here:

```
dialog.setVisible(true);
//todo is filled correctly IF pressed "convert Button" the second time
if (!s.contentEquals("")) {
  words[j] = s;
  hs.add(s);
  s = "";
}
```

A modal `dialog` will block at the `dialog.setVisible(true)` line until the `write` button is pressed, and your `ActionListener` will process the Event, setting `s = newWord.getText().trim();` and disposing the `dialog`.

An only after this event (`write` pressed) is processed the lines of code following the `dialog.setVisible(true)` will be executed, and `s` will contain the value of the `newWord.getText().trim()`.

With "normal" (non-modal) `dialog` you are not blocking at `dialog.setVisible(true)` hence the

```
if (!s.contentEquals(""))
```

line will check some value of `s` that was not yet set (you have not pressed `write` button yet), the test will fail, and the code in `if` block will be not executed.

I would recommend you to debug the code Setting the breakpoints on the `if` line and in the `ActionListener` of the `write` button. Then you will understand better when the code is executed and what the values of your fields are.

Comment: Hey, many thanks that solved the whole problem :) now the HashSet is filled correctly at the first time i press "convert" and insert the words.
yes it did open a dialog for every unknown word without the modal flag.

i dont understand exactly why but i'll find that answer.
`dialog = new JDialog(mainFrame,JDialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);`